# Calculating outstanding principal

Tags: sql, mysql, data-science, mysql-workbench, data-analysis

I have 2 tables in MySQL database. The table 1 has following columns.

1. a. loan id
2. b. loan start date
3. c. due date
4. d. principal amount
5. e. markup amount
6. d. late payment fees amount (This is applied when repayment is done
   after due date.

| loan id | loan start date | due date | principal amount | markupamount | late payment fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23-05-2020 | 26-05-2020 | 10000 | 650 | 150 |
| 2 | 23-05-2020 | 26-05-2020 | 10000 | 650 | 150 |
| 3 | 24-05-2020 | 27-05-2020 | 20000 | 1300 | 150 |

The table 2 has following columns.

1. a. loan id
2. b. repayment amount
3. c. repayment date
4. d. description

| loan id | repayment amount | repayment date | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 24-05-2020 | Customer Payment |
| 1 | 5800 | 28-05-2020 | Customer Payment |
| 2 | 7000 | 25-05-2020 | Customer Payment |
| 2 | 3650 | 26-05-2020 | Customer Payment |
| 3 | 21450 | 27-05-2020 | Customer Payment |

The result table that I want

| date | outstanding principal |
| --- | --- |
| 23-05-2020 | 20000 |
| 24-05-2020 | 35650 |
| 25-05-2020 | 29300 |
| 26-05-2020 | 25650 |
| 27-05-2020 | 20000 |
| 28-05-2020 | 0 |

The loan id column is common in both tables. But there are some loan ids in table 1 which are not in table 2 because there is no repayment against those loans' ids now. I want to calculate principal outstanding of those loans whose due date has not passed against every loan start date such that when a repayment is done, first markup amount is deducted from repayment amount and then principal amount. . I want to take repayment amount when description = 'Customer payment'. there is one problem that repayments are done in installments means if customer pay in 2 installments in different dates then there will be 2 different rows against those loan id. The problem is that there are some missing dates in loan start date column because no loan was issued on that day but on that dates repayment was done. So I also want to include those dates on which no new loan was issued but repayment was done

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and publish your code attempt.

Comment: The result you want is not that much clear
The data belongs to which loan?
Can you put some mathematical data of how your data is to be populated?

Comment: sample data should be representative - 'some loan ids in table 1 which are not in table 2'   this is not the case in the sample. 'loans whose due date has not passed ' - I don't get this all dates are in the past as of today. should it be the case that all payments should be on the due date?